# How do I get the text inside of the <a> This Text </a> tags using cURL?

Tags: php, parsing, curl, html-parsing

I got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()" with this code.  I want to capture the text of a link not the source (I don't know what its called).Could someone please explain to me my error or tell me a different way of doing this? Here is my code:

```
<?php

$target_url = "SITE I WANT";
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

// make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a/text()");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    storeLink($url,$target_url);
    echo "<br />Link stored: $url";
}
$id = "12";
   $query = "DELETE FROM links WHERE id<=$id";
    if(!mysql_query($query))
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
        ?>
```

Comment: Check the content of `$hrefs`. Maybe you should instead use `/html/body//a` and then, on each element, try to retrieve its text.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that I would do this with? I'm generally new to this all.

Comment: Look at the @Adidi response, he/she is coding what I just commented

Comment: It's a he thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);
$anchors = $selector->query('/html/body//a');

foreach($anchors as $a) { 
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    echo($text . ' : ' . $href . '<br />');

}
```